# Create number of dynamic NSTimers not repeating on very first load, fine after that

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

I am creating a number (~5) NSTimer instances from data stored in a SQLite database using the following code below:

```
-(void)setupNotificationTimer:(NSDictionary *)timerDetails{

    NSLog(@"TIMER REPEATS VALUE: %@", [timerDetails objectForKey:@"repeats"]);
    NSLog(@"INTERVAL: %f", [[timerDetails objectForKey:@"interval"] floatValue]);

    bool repeat = [[timerDetails objectForKey:@"repeats"] boolValue];
    if (repeat) {
        NSLog(@"Should Repeat");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Should Not Repeat");
    }

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[[timerDetails objectForKey:@"interval"] floatValue]
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(fireTimer:)
                                   userInfo:timerDetails
                                    repeats:repeat];
    [timer fire];
    [timers addObject:timer]; //'timers' is a property of the AppDelegate
}

-(void)fireTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"Timer Fired");
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[dict objectForKey:@"notificationName"] object:nil];
}
```

When I setup these timers the very first time the app loads the timer is setup correctly as the NSLog output below shows but does not repeat despite clearly being set to repeat. Each timer fires once then does not continue.

```
2013-04-03 11:12:53.541 Test[2635:752b] TIMER REPEATS VALUE: 1
2013-04-03 11:12:53.542 Test[2635:752b] INTERVAL: 10.000000
2013-04-03 11:12:53.543 Test[2635:752b] Should Repeat
2013-04-03 11:12:53.544 Test[2635:752b] Timer Fired
```

The strange thing happens when I close the app and then re-open it, the timers are created and actually fire repeatedly. This app is also a universal iPhone and iPad app and I only seem to get this behaviour when running the app on iPhone. I really am stumped by this and any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

As requested the code to cancel the timers:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{        
    NSArray *viewControllersSet = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    if (viewControllersSet.count > 1 && [viewControllersSet objectAtIndex:viewControllersSet.count-2] == self) {
        // View is disappearing because a new view controller was pushed onto the stack
        NSLog(@"New view controller was pushed");
    } else if ([viewControllersSet indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound) {
        // View is disappearing because it was popped from the stack
        NSLog(@"View controller was popped");
        for(int i = 0; i < [[appDelegate timers] count]; i ++){
            NSTimer *timer = [[appDelegate timers] objectAtIndex:i];
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
        [[appDelegate timers] removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your timerDeatails dictionary might have got changed...that sends NO to nstimer

Comment: @AnoopVaidya you might need to clarify your thinking there - the OP prints the logs which show the value of `repeat` as being `YES` (printing the `Should Repeat`) there is no way that the dictionary can change the value of a local variable.

Comment: @Paul.s: I thought if this method is again called and then the repeat is read as NO.

Comment: I don't know the answer though you can try few things ... Take BOOL instead of bool and remove [timer fire]; statement you don't need to fire it explicitly... Let me know if that works

Comment: Can you show the code (if any) that cancels the timers? or are they just ongoing forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an NSTimer does not fire after being created with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, it usually means that it has not been attached to the correct runloop. Could it be that your method setupNotificationTimer() is called with different runloops during initialization and when returning to the foreground? (i.e. in the context of a different thread or similar)

This code would work around the problem:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:[[timerDetails objectForKey:@"interval"] floatValue]
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(fireTimer:)
                               userInfo:timerDetails
                                repeats:repeat];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

This ensures that your timers are scheduled on the main runloop and will fire.

Comment: I still get the same thing happening when I add this to my code. I don't understand how it can work perfectly for iPad but not for iPhone.

Comment: Sorry for the discussion in the comments here, I don't have enough reputation to comment on the main question. Can you try to schedule a dummy timer by using the NSRunLoop:addTimer:forMode: method from your App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method? The timer should just print a message to the console. If that one fires, it means that your main runloop is active and the timers theoretically should work.

Comment: I appreciate the help you've given thanks. I tried creating one in the AppDelegate and it worked so must not be being added to the RunLoop. Everywhere I have read has said pretty much leave this alone. I've solved my issed by just initialising the NSTimers on the AppDelegate and have them constantly running when the app is loaded even if they are not needed. I've voted up your comments and i'll accept your answer when I am able to. Thanks again.